# getting error with plot with panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

i am trying to creat plot from that data

```
   Word    count
17  in      2
15  on      2
33  the     2
8   you     2
0   valar   1
29  all     1
24  +       1
25  hotel   1
26  are     1
```

with this code :

```
%matplotlib inline   
words_df[words_df['count'] > 10000].plot(x='Word',kind='bar')
```

but i got this message error :

> TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

can you give me an idea where is the problem ???

Comment: how does your data frame look like? can you post output of `print(words_df.head())`

Comment: it look like what i put in my post .            Word    count
17  in      2
15  on      2
33  the     2
8   you     2
0   valar   1
29  all     1
24  +       1
25  hotel   1
26  are     1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[df['count'] > 1000].set_index('Word').plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Demo (using your sample data set):

```
In [184]: df
Out[184]:
     Word  count
17     in      2
15     on      2
33    the      2
8     you      2
0   valar      1
29    all      1
24      +      1
25  hotel      1
26    are      1

In [185]: df.dtypes
Out[185]:
Word     object
count     int64   # <--------- NOTE !
dtype: object

In [187]: df[df['count'] > 1].set_index('Word').plot.bar(rot=0, grid=True)
Out[187]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xd608ac8>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i tried it but it gave me this error:   TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: @yok, it means that your `count` column has non-numeric dtype. What does `print(df.dtypes)` output?

Comment: Word     object   /    count     int64     / dtype: object

Comment: thank you @MaxU it work well now, but can i know what was the problem exactely ?

Comment: @yok, as i already said before that error means that the `value` (Y-axis) column (`count` in your case) has non-numeric dtype (object, datetime, etc.)